# printf zero padded string

Tags: perl, awk, printf

The format of MAC addresses varies with the platform.
E.g. on HPUX I could get something like:

```
0:0:c:7:ac:1e
```

While Linux gives me

```
00:00:0c:07:ac:1e
```

I used to use awk in a kornshell script on CentOS5 to format this to `00000c07ac1e` like shown below.

```
MAC="0:0:c:7:ac:1e"  
echo $MAC | awk -F: '{printf( "%02s%02s%02s%02s%02s%02s\n", $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6)}'
```

Unfortunately our admin server now is Ubuntu 14LTS with a newer version of awk which doesn't support the zero padding in the `%s` format anymore and I get an undesired `0 0 c 7ac1e`

So I now switched to perl and do:

```
echo $MAC | perl -ne '{@A=split(":"); printf( "%02s%02s%02s%02s%02s%02s", @A)}'
```

As this may break too in upcoming releases I am looking for a more robust but still compact way to format the string.

Comment: What version of GNU `awk` are you using. I tried this on mine, and it seem fine. I have GNU Awk 3.1.5. Type `awk --version` to find the version.

Comment: my awk is GNU Awk 4.0.1  .  I like ikegami's 2nd solution. It is short and seems to be a bit faster if run on many MAC addresses, although I must admit that the pattern repetition is a bit awkward to read. Unfortunately I cannot give any points as my account does not have enough credits yet.  As the 'echo' command has an LF at the end I think the \n in the printf can be omitted.

Comment: I'm going to see if I can find a difference. Unfortunately, all of the Linux systems at my company are still using 3.1.5. I'm going to see if I can diff between 3.1.5 and 4.0.1 and find out what broke in between.

Answer (score 2):

Your Perl snippet will not break in future releases. This is basic functionality. Changing it will break many, many programs. (Plus, Perl has a mechanism for introducing backwards incompatible changes without breaking existing program.)

Cleaned up:

```
echo "$MAC" | perl -ne'@F=split(/:/); printf("%02s%02s%02s%02s%02s%02s\n", @F)'
```

Shorter:

```
echo "$MAC" | perl -ne'printf "%02s%02s%02s%02s%02s%02s\n", split /:/'
```

Without the repetition:

```
echo "$MAC" | perl -ple'$_ = join ":", map sprintf("%02s", $_), split /:/'
```

There's `-a` if you want something more `awk`ish:

```
echo "$MAC" | perl -F: -aple'$_ = join ":", map sprintf("%02s", $_), @F'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were dealing with a number rather than hex, you could use `%.Xd` to indicate you want at least `X` digits.

```
$ awk -F: '{printf( "%.2d%.2d\n", $1, $2)}' <<< "0:23"
0023
^^
two digits
```

From The [GNU Awk User’s Guide #5.5.3 Modifiers for printf Formats](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Format-Modifiers):

> .prec
>
> A period followed by an integer constant specifies the precision to
>   use when printing. The meaning of the precision varies by control
>   letter:
>
> %d, %i, %o, %u, %x, %X
>
> Minimum number of digits to print.

In this case, you need a more general approach to deal with each one of the blocks of the MAC address. You can loop through the elements and add a `0` in case their length is just `1`:

```
awk -F: '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)        #loop through the elements
            {
                if (length($i)==1)   #if length is 1
                    printf("0")      #add a 0
                printf ("%s", $i)    #print the rest
            }
            print ""                 #print a new line at the end
        }' <<< "0:0:c:7:ac:1e"
```

This returns:

```
00000c07ac1e
^^  ^^  ^^
  ^^  ^^  ^^
```

Note `awk '...' <<< "$MAC"` is the same as `echo "$MAC" | awk '...'`.

Comment: @Jidder now it is handled broader. Also, no need to downvote.

Comment: @fedorqui i haven't and i can't downvote twice anyway ?

Comment: @Jidder ok thanks. Well, apparently in the [Perl] tag people downvotes quite fastly (and don't come back to check if the problems were solved) and so did they.

Answer (score 0):

Bit long but should be pretty robust

```
 awk -F: '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){while(length($i)<2)$i=0$i;printf "%s",$i;}print ""}'
```

---

#### How it works

1.Loop through fields
2.Whilst the field is less than 2 characters long add zeros to the front
3.print the field
4.print newline character at end.